# Is it possible to do HLS streaming over HTTP/2, and will it be better latency-wise than over HTTP/1.1?

Tags: http, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, http2, exoplayer

Since HTTP/2.0 leverages request multiplexing, I've been wondering whether using HTTP/2.0 over HTTP/1.1 for HLS streaming.

My current HLS stream seems to be using HTTP/1.1, at least, that's what I gathered when I inspected my Native HLS Playback Chrome extension in the network tab, with all the Media Playlists and TS chunks being transfered over HTTP/1.1.

At this point, I've found no information on HLS over HTTP/2.0, but some info on MPEG-DASH over HTTP/2.0, so I'm wondering whether HLS over HTTP/2.0 is even possible. If it is, will I get lower latency between server and client devices?

Related question: does Exoplayer support HLS over HTTP/2.0?

Comment: If you want low latency, don't use a segmented transport like DASH or HLS.  With some hacks, you can certainly lower their latency but it's far less complicated to use straight-up HTTP Progressive.

Comment: Does this mean playing with websockets?

Comment: No need for web socket if the data is flowing in just one direction.  You can have a server assemble a stream and send it over HTTP as-is.  No extra layers necessary.  Playback can be a simple `<video>` element to a certain extent, but you'll want to use MSE to have control over buffering and what not.

Comment: That'd probably be great for browsers, but my priority target is Android devices with `Exoplayer`. Though maybe I could replace that with a WebView with a single `<video>` element...

Comment: Even regular MediaPlayer supports HTTP Progressive...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, no it won’t reduce latency.

Comment: I thought it could, because of the parallel requests and all. BTW, would migrating form TS to CMAF reduce latency?

Comment: That is a complicated question. Generally, TS is as low latency as possible. Low latency cmaf can match it however (standard cmaf is higher latency). mpd can be lower than m3u8 due to how it’s structured. But there are non standard extensions to m3u8 to reduce that down to mpd levels. Generally your latency will be determined by the player much more than the format.

Comment: I'm using `Exoplayer`, and I'm confused on what else I can alter (other than the `DefaultLoadControl` buffer parameters) to ensure that the latency is at a minimum. Should I just add the initial segment number the server assigned by 1?

Answer (score 0):

HLS and Dash are protocols on top of HTTP, and are e.g. defined in terms of HTTP GET requests. They will work on HTTP/1.1 as well as HTTP/2. The only question is whether the client supports HTTP/2, and whether the server which is serving the stream supports HTTP/2. Those questions would need to be asked for each application individually.

My estimate is that HTTP/2 support wouldn't yield too much advantage for those use-cases. HTTP/2 is best at multiplexing lots of small requests over a single TCP connection, and avoiding the overhead of creating new connections. With video streaming, there are not that many concurrent small requests - instead the client fetches larger chunks piece by piece. This should work pretty fine on top of HTTP/1.1 connections with keep-alive (which also doesn't require a new connection per request - it just doesn't support parallel requests).

HTTP/1.1 might be even more efficient than HTTP/2 for this special use-case, since there is not the overhead of another flow-control mechanism on top of TCP.

Comment: Guess I'll have to stick with HTTP/1.1 then. Also, what about HTTP/1.1 + Chunked Transfer Encoding? Is CTE already part of the package with HLS or MPEG-DASH? If not, should I enable it?

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 a good reference is [this paper](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/bib/files/paper_330.pdf). And [this one](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/7016610/file/7016623.pdf) shows how a lower latency can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Apple released recently its spec for low latency. It includes HTTP/2 push support for very low latency.

See their specification [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/protocol_extension_for_low-latency_hls_preliminary_specification)

It'll probably deliver your video data as fast as other real-time protocol into safari and iOS. :)